# How to embed script for Google schemas in Mandrill template

Tags: json, mandrill, google-schemas

I'm trying to embed a snippet of code in my mandrill template in order to enable Google Schemas but whenever I try to publish the template Mandrill reloads and the code disappears.

The code is:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Order",
  "merchant": {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "mycompany.com"
  },
  "orderNumber": "*|ORDERNUMBER|*",
  "priceCurrency": "*|CURRENCY|*",
  "price": "*|ORDERTOTALAMOUNT|*",
  "acceptedOffer": *|ITEMOFFEREDLIST|*
}
</script>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We currently support using Microdata to embed schemas in templates. We're still looking at ways we may be able to support the JSON-LD scripts for templates.

Comment: Looks like JSON-LD is still not supported

Comment: This is simply absurd and not documented at all.